# how can I test whether a bean property is writeable?

Tags: groovy

Currently I'm using the following code to check if a bean property can be set

```
class Foo {

  def baz = 'baz'

  String getBar() {
    'bar'
  }
}


def f = new Foo()
assert f.hasProperty('baz').setter
assert !f.hasProperty('bar').setter
```

The `getSetter()` method I'm calling is defined on `MetaBeanProperty`, which is the runtime type of the `MetaProperty` instance returned by `hasProperty`. I'm sure there must be a better way to check whether a bean property is writeable, any suggestions?

Comment: in your example the property has both getter and setter

Comment: @injecteer the `bar` property does not have a setter

Comment: yes, it does! It wouldn't have a setter if it were defined as `private`

Comment: @injecteer my testing indicates that you are incorrect

Comment: @injecteer `baz` is a property which has getter and setter, but `bar` is not. It is a plain method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using `respondsTo("setX")`:

```
class Foo {

  def baz = 'baz'

  String getBar() {
    'bar'
  }
}

foo = new Foo()

assert !foo.respondsTo('setBar')
assert foo.respondsTo('setBaz')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following approach numerous time and it seems to work well:

```
class Foo {
    String name

    private int _age
    private Date _dob

    void setAge(int age){ _age = age }

    Date getDateOfBirth(){ _dob }
}

boolean hasSetterFor(String propName){
    Foo.metaClass.methods.find { MetaMethod mm-> mm.name == "set${propName.capitalize()}" }    
}

println "Name: ${hasSetterFor('name')}"
println "Age : ${hasSetterFor('age')}"
println "DOB : ${hasSetterFor('dateOfBirth')}"
```

Basically, you are looking for presence of the implicit setter generated by a Groovy property or the explicit setter coded by the developer. Also, you can further filter the search for public, non-static methods as needed.